# How to connect 3 wire cooktop to 4 wire power supply

Tags: electrical

I would like to connect my new 3 wired 208/240V cooktop, to a 4 wire power supply. The voltage of the new cooktop is the same as my previous one, with the only difference I can see being that the new one has 3 wires, red-green-black, as opposed to 4 wires, red-green-black-white.

The junction box itself has 4 wires, red-copper-black-white with the coper wire being wrapped around a screw in the box.

My circuit breaker is 120/240V.

I was hoping to get some advice on whether this is something an average Joe could do, or if I should call an electrician.

According to my basic understanding of the instructions I received with the new top, the following could be an option:

Red to Red /
Black to Black /
Green to Copper /
Cap the white wire?

- The instructions said "The neutral conductor is not required for the operation of the appliance. The potential at the power supply electrical connections shall be 150V to ground or less."

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The new cook top does not need or use neutral, so it is right to just cap the white wire off.

The new cook top only uses the two hots and the ground.  The old one probably used a 120 volt circuit in it for a receptacle/light/clock, so it needed the neutral wire to have a 120 volt circuit, one hot plus the white.

Comment: And then they confuse things by having Figure 4 there… Cheap out printing one manual for multiple stoves, adding risk to not wiring it up correctly. Sigh.